# Manga where a partially artificial guy is put into stasis and wakes up in a future with magic

Tags: story-identification, manga

The premise was pretty unique to me as it was centered around this robotic/android/cyborg guy who was put into stasis, and wakes up to a future where the Earth is now a world of magic, monsters, and demons and so on. Except he doesn't know this and thinks that it's a entirely different world from earth due to what his 'mom'/creator told him before putting him in stasis on the space ship he was to use. He then decided to help out a demon girl after she begged for his help.

All of that was within the first 2-3 chapters from what I remember.

Answer (score 1):

#### [*Iseikai Tensei*](https://mangakakalot.com/manga/jb924281)

> Noah, the last survivor from Earth, aims for a new universe on the spaceship that was handed down to him by his mother who was a scientist. What he arrives at is a planet where living things possess magic. When he is out doing field work, he meets a girl who proclaims herself as the demon lord's daughter.
>
> The cyborg youth will traverse a planet full of mysteries in this iseikai sci-fi fantasy.

Comment: There are quite a few sources with the same synopsis of this, could you [edit] this so that it includes the correct link from where you got it from as I just picked one from the selection available. In the future please include the link yourself. Also if you add a `>` at the start of a paragraph it will indicate it is a quote to differentiate it from ordinary text.